# front-end upload function of a website

Tags: file-upload, upload, image-uploading

I run a site that could let my visitor to upload 3D file and view it online instantly. Recently i upgraded from Shared Hosting to VPS and i found that this upload function is not working, and http 500 error existed.

I am thinking whether "upload_tmp_dir" in php ini relevant to my case. I set the value to /tmp and it seems the problem is still exist. That makes me think that /tmp may not be accessible by my visitors as this requires root access to my server. Please correct me if i am wrong.

So, what value should i set in upload_tmp_dir in order to let my visitor to access the folder?

Many thanks!

Comment: have you given proper permission

Comment: I just set permission to /tmp by using the following code: #sudo chmod -R ugo+rwx /tmp . Which gives all users the right to access /tmp. Please direct me if i am wrong.